# How to use different CSS classes with each module to make it grid

Tags: php, templates, joomla, joomla-template

This is this basic module system I am creating to make a 6 column grid system in joomla template yes I have successfully created different classes with each grid i.e. if the there are only 4 modules enabled from the back end of joomla the class dc-modules4 would be enabled automatically and so on, but I need help to call a class to hold a single module but right now when I call CSS class it holds all the modules and wrap it with dc-module4 so that I can style that class in CSS here is code this will help you understand it.

```
<?php
function Top(){
    $modules = array();
    $modules["top1"] = '<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top1" style="xhtml" />';
    $modules["top2"] = '<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top2" style="xhtml" />';
    $modules["top3"] = '<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top3" style="xhtml" />';
    $modules["top4"] = '<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top4" style="xhtml" />';
    $modules["top5"] = '<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top5" style="xhtml" />';
    $modules["top6"] = '<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top6" style="xhtml" />';
        foreach($modules as $module => $name){
            echo '<div class="dc-modules">'.$name.'</div>';
        }
}

if($this->countModules('top1')){
    $mod[0] = 'mod1';
}
if($this->countModules('top2')){
    $mod[1] = 'mod2';
}
if($this->countModules('top3')){
    $mod[2] = 'mod3';
}
if($this->countModules('top4')){
    $mod[3] = 'mod4';
}
if($this->countModules('top5')){
    $mod[4] = 'mod5';
}
if($this->countModules('top6')){
    $mod[5] = 'mod6';
}
$result = count($mod);
    if($result == 6){
        echo '<div class="dc-modules6">';
        echo Top();
        echo '</div>';
    }
    if($result == 5){
        echo '<div class="dc-modules5">';
        echo Top();
        echo '</div>';
    }
    if($result == 4){
        echo '<div class="dc-modules4">';
        echo Top();
        echo '</div>';
    }
    if($result == 3){
        echo '<div class="dc-modules3">';
        echo Top();
        echo '</div>';
    }
    if($result == 2){
        echo '<div class="dc-modules2">';
        echo Top();
        echo '</div>';
    }
    if($result == 1){
        echo '<div class="dc-modules1">';
        echo Top();
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

after spending two hours I just came out with the solutions for grid system hope you guys can take advantage with this, hope someone will improve my code in a better way so here it is

```
<?php
    if($this->countModules('top1')){
        $modules["top1"] = '<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top1" style="xhtml" />';
    }
    if($this->countModules('top2')){
        $modules["top2"] = '<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top2" style="xhtml" />';
    }
    if($this->countModules('top3')){
        $modules["top3"] = '<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top3" style="xhtml" />';
    }
    if($this->countModules('top4')){
        $modules["top4"] = '<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top4" style="xhtml" />';
    }
    if($this->countModules('top5')){
        $modules["top5"] = '<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top5" style="xhtml" />';
    }
    if($this->countModules('top6')){
        $modules["top6"] = '<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top6" style="xhtml" />';
    }

if(isset($modules)){

    $result = count($modules);

    foreach($modules as $module => $name){
        if($result == 6){
            echo '<div class="dc-modules6">';
            echo $name;
            echo '</div>';
        }
        if($result == 5){
            echo '<div class="dc-modules5">';
            echo $name;
            echo '</div>';
        }
        if($result == 4){
            echo '<div class="dc-modules4">';
            echo $name;
            echo '</div>';
        }
        if($result == 3){
            echo '<div class="dc-modules3">';
            echo $name;
            echo '</div>';
        }
        if($result == 2){
            echo '<div class="dc-modules2">';
            echo $name;
            echo '</div>';
        }
        if($result == 1){
            echo '<div class="dc-modules1">';
            echo $name;
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```